# freeform multipage reset some values from other pages

Tags: solspace-freeform, extension, hook

I have a multi-page form set up as following :

question 1 > question 2 > question 3 >

question 4 **if answered yes** > question 5 
question 4 **if answered no** > question 6

All my questions have a return to last step button.

now my problem is that if someone answers **yes** on question 4, then answers question 5 and goes back to question 4 and set it to no and answers question 6
both values will be set. This is a problem for me since the the result page will depend on the answers on every question.

I have tried using the extension hooks, but every page only has the $_POST values of that given page.

Does anyone know a way to clear the value when another value is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are good in backend development, I suggest you to manipulate data when it actually start insert in database. Use **freeform_module_insert_begin** hook.